# C# HTTP Error 400 - Invalid Hostname Simple Http Listener

Tags: c#

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace HttpServer
{
    class Program
    {
        // Main method
        static void Main()
        {
            using var listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:10060/");

            listener.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Listening on port 10060...");

            // Request handler
            while (true)
            {
                HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
                HttpListenerRequest req = context.Request;

                Console.WriteLine($"Received request for {req.Url}");

                // TODO: Login stuff
                Uri? url = req.Url;
                if (url.ToString() == "http://localhost:10060/login")
                {
                    using HttpListenerResponse resp = context.Response;
                    resp.Headers.Set("Content-Type", "text/plain");

                    string data = "Hello there!";
                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                    resp.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;

                    using Stream ros = resp.OutputStream;
                    ros.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

The above code is a simple http server that listens for requests. The above code works when going to localhost:10060 in the browser. However, I want to access this server via the machine's IP address on the same network through a different device. When doing so, it results in a bad request due to the invalid hostname. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: When you add a prefix like that, you are telling Windows HTTP API to only forward HTTP requests matching the binding `localhost:10060`. That's why no other requests (like the ones from another machine) can be received. Try `http://*:10060/` if you want a quick fix. You might learn more about Windows HTTP API from posts like https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: I tried this, but I get "Unhandled exception. System.Net.HttpListenerException (5): Access is denied." Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Run this app as administrator and see what happens.

Comment: It worked when running as administer, is there a way to get it to work without running as administer?

Comment: Different prefix/bindings require different permissions, so if you do want a wildcard prefix or a prefix to a certain network adapter, then administrator permission is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

try using the ip address instead of localhost. or try *:10060

Answer (score -1):

In another machine try to modify firewall rule to allow port 80.

1. Windows defender firewall with advance security on local Computer.
2. Inbound rules
3. New Rule
4. Select the port, Next, TCP, specific local port, type 80
5. Allow the connection and save the rule.

Let us know if this worked.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that can be directly implemented in the C# code if possible. I think the problem is that I specified "localhost" inside the listener url. However, using anything that isn't localhost ends up giving me an "Access is denied." error.

Comment: I meant to say in machine where localhost listening incoming connections.   http://localhost:10060/ and create rule to allow port 10060 .